# Exibição de relatório por valor digitado pelo cliente

Tags: php

Eu quero que ele me exiba a quantidade que o cliente digitar no campo quantidade.

Código HTML:

```
    <style>
    header form input { display: block; margin-top:10px;  }
</style>
<header>
<form action="etiqueta.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" placeholder="Nome do Produto" name="nomeproduto">
<input type="text" placeholder="Outra Informação" name="outrainformacao">
<input type="text" placeholder="Marca" name="marca">
<input type="text" placeholder="Quantidade" name="quantidade"><BR>
<button>Carregar Etiquetas</button>
</form>
</header>
```

Esse é o código etiqueta.php

```
<?php


 $nomeproduto = $_POST['nomeproduto'];
 $outrainformacao = $_POST['outrainformacao'];
 $marca = $_POST['marca'];
 $quantidade = $_POST['quantidade'];

 $quantidademaxima = 4;

 while($quantidade >= $quantidademaxima) {

        echo "$nomeproduto e $outrainformacao e $marca e $quantidade";

        $quantidade++;

 }
```

Eu quero que a quantidade que o cliente digitou no campo formulário seja exibido no código etiqueta.php . Vocês podem me ajudar por gentileza.

Comment: Você já  está fazendo isso. Qual a dificuldade?

Comment: Quando eu digito o valor, ele entra em loop

Comment: Se o valor for maior igual a 4 você fará um loop *enquanto for maior que 4*, incrementando a cada iteração. Ou seja, sempre será maior que 4 e o loop nunca termina.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss. Sim, eu compreeendi. Entretanto, tem alguma possibilidade de exibiri somente o que o usuario digitar ?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Quando eu coloco o valor == Funciona, porém, acima de 4 não funciona.

Comment: Porque entra em loop infinito... é só você rever a sua lógica e definir exatamente o que precisa fazer.

Comment: Só um palpite, não é mandatório ou definitivo, mas onde está `$quantidade++;` faça `$quantidade--;`.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Obrigado meu jovem, deu certo.

Comment: PS: Talvez para um exercício seja suficiente, mas se o código for comercial eu acho que não é a melhor solução. Pessoalmente acho que o caminho seria informar ao usuário que o valor extrapolou o estoque e voltar o foco no front-end para o input que seleciona a quantidade com o valor no máximo disponível. Eu sugeri o `$quantidade--;` somente para direcionar o pensamento.

Answer (score 1):

Basta colocar desta forma:

```
<?php
 $nomeproduto = $_POST['nomeproduto'];
 $outrainformacao = $_POST['outrainformacao'];
 $marca = $_POST['marca'];
 $quantidade = $_POST['quantidade'];
 $quantidademaxima = 1;

    while($quantidade >= $quantidademaxima) {

            echo "$nomeproduto e $outrainformacao e $marca e $quantidade". "<br>";

            $quantidade--;

     }
```